# Find all prime numbers in form of $a^4-b^4,$ with $a$ and $b$ positives integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all prime numbers in form of $a^4-b^4,$ with a and b positives integers.

I think I solved half of the question, $(a^2+b^2)(a^2-b^2) = p.$
Is necessary that $a^2+b^2$ equal to $p$ and $a^2-b^2$ equal to $1$ to be prime.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unless you specify *positive* primes, you can also have $a^2+b^2=-p, a^2-b^2=-1.$

Comment: The answer have to be positive primes, sorry.

Comment: Your reasoning is fine and $a^2-b^2=1 \iff a=1 \quad \land \quad b=0$

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was right hahaha.

Comment: What can you conclude from $a^2-b^2=1?$

Comment: Dont have the possibility to have -p if the a and b are positives integers.